# Save image to sdcard in Android

Tags: android, image, webview, save

I have a ImageView and a WebView where I am trying to show the same image.

I have downloaded the image with picasso and all works well during the download.

When I save the image into sdcard to show into a ImageView and into WebView I have a  problem: My ImageView allways shows the last image downloaded and this is ok. But, after I save the image to show into WebView, my WebView always shows the first image downloaded and not the last downloaded.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

```
    public void downloadimage(){
      Bitmap bm=MyGetImage(1);
      saveImageToExternalStorageToShow(bm);

      bm=MyGetImage(2);
      saveImageToExternalStorageToShow(bm);//into this method, webview doesn´t show image correctly
    }

    public void saveImageToExternalStorageToShow(Bitmap image) {
        String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        try
        {
            ImageView imv= (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ImvTeste);
           //ok-shows the image downloaded 
           imv.setImageBitmap(image);

            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            String fileName = "sala.jpg"; //DateFormat.format("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss", System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
            File file = new File(fullPath, fileName);

            boolean b=false;
            if(!file.exists()) {
                b=file.createNewFile();
            } else {
                 b=file.delete();
                 b=file.createNewFile();
            }

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            String imagePath = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();//"file://"+ base + "/test.jpg";
            String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
            //Problem here-wedview allways shows the first image downloaded
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", ""); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the image being cached in the WebView.

Try calling `webView.clearCache(true)` before showing the second image and it should work propperly.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are correct. This solved my problem.